# Four coplanar points on a skew quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, 3d

$P,Q,R,S$ are four coplanar points on the sides $AB,BC,CD,DA$ of a skew quadrilateral. The product $\frac{AP}{PB}.\frac{BQ}{QC}.\frac{CR}{RD}.\frac{DS}{SA}$ equals?

**My attempt:**

> I was not able to even start the problem, because I have never worked
>   on a skew quadrilateral. Any hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be  $1$. For coplanarity all points must lie at same height from base of cuboid that creates skew quadrilateral.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution but rather a "fake solve".

Consider point D to coincide with point A(we may assume $D \rightarrow A, and \lim_{D \rightarrow A} \frac{DS}{SA} =1$. Then in $∆ABC$, the answer is just $1$ due to Ceva's theorem.

I am looking forward to a proper solution.

Comment: I too late the OP, have never worked on skew quadrilaterals. I just came across this problem recently.